# dijit tree overflows div but does not scroll

Tags: tree, scroll, overflow, dojo

I have a simple page with several divs which I intend to populate with various dijit widgets. I have one div which properly scrolls if I insert too much text, but if I insert a dijit Tree, the tree items overflow the div but no scrolling occurs. The code is below, with styles inline for clarity. I'm willing to use declarative mode for the tree if that will make it easier, but maybe you can show me how to fix it up as-is so that the dijitTree will stay inside its own div and scroll.

Thanks. Code below:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test dijit Tree Overflow</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        @import "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.7.2/dojo/resources/dojo.css";
        @import "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.7.2/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css";
        @import "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.7.2/dijit/themes/dijit.css";
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.7.2/dojo/dojo.js" djConfig="isDebug:true, parseOnLoad: true"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        dojo.require("dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore");
        dojo.require("dijit.Tree");
    </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var snidTree = [{ id: 'tn1', label: 'Tree Node 1', },{ id: 'tn2', label: 'Tree Node 2', },{ id: 'tn3', label: 'Tree Node 3', },{ id: 'tn4', label: 'Tree Node 4', },{ id: 'tn5', label: 'Tree Node 5', },{ id: 'tn6', label: 'Tree Node 6', },{ id: 'tn7', label: 'Tree Node 7', },{ id: 'tn8', label: 'Tree Node 8', },{ id: 'tn9', label: 'Tree Node 9', },{ id: 'tn10', label: 'Tree Node 10', },{ id: 'tn11', label: 'Tree Node 11', },{ id: 'tn12', label: 'Tree Node 12', },{ id: 'tn13', label: 'Tree Node 13', },{ id: 'tn14', label: 'Tree Node 14', },{ id: 'tn15', label: 'Tree Node 15', },{ id: 'tn16', label: 'Tree Node 16', },{ id: 'tn17', label: 'Tree Node 17', },{ id: 'tn18', label: 'Tree Node 18', },{ id: 'tn19', label: 'Tree Node 19', },{ id: 'tn20', label: 'Tree Node 20', },{ id: 'tn21', label: 'Tree Node 21', },{ id: 'tn22', label: 'Tree Node 22', },{ id: 'tn23', label: 'Tree Node 23', },{ id: 'tn24', label: 'Tree Node 24', },{ id: 'tn25', label: 'Tree Node 25', },{ id: 'tn26', label: 'Tree Node 26', },{ id: 'tn27', label: 'Tree Node 27', },{ id: 'tn28', label: 'Tree Node 28', },{ id: 'tn29', label: 'Tree Node 29', },{ id: 'tn30', label: 'Tree Node 30', },{ id: 'tn31', label: 'Tree Node 31', },{ id: 'tn32', label: 'Tree Node 32', },{ id: 'tn33', label: 'Tree Node 33', },{ id: 'tn34', label: 'Tree Node 34', },{ id: 'tn35', label: 'Tree Node 35', },{ id: 'tn36', label: 'Tree Node 36', },{ id: 'tn37', label: 'Tree Node 37', },{ id: 'tn38', label: 'Tree Node 38', },{ id: 'tn39', label: 'Tree Node 39', },{ id: 'tn40', label: 'Tree Node 40', } ];

function prepare() {
        var store = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({
            data: { identifier: 'id', label : 'label', items: snidTree }
        });
        var treeModel = new dijit.tree.ForestStoreModel({ store: store });
        var treeControl = new dijit.Tree({
            model: treeModel,
            showRoot: false,
            _createTreeNode: function(/*Object*/ args){
                var tnode = new dijit._TreeNode(args);
                tnode.labelNode.innerHTML = args.label;
                return tnode;
            },
        onClick: function(c,n,e) {
              myTreeClick(this,c,n,e);
          }
        }, "left" );
}
dojo.ready(prepare);
function myTreeClick(tree,child,node,event) {
  dojo.byId("footer").innerHTML = child.label + " was clicked";
}
</script>
</head>
<body class="tundra">
<div id='header' style="width:100%;
    background: #FC8;
    position: absolute;
    height: 30px;
    font-size: 150%;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;">HEADING GOES HERE</div>
<div id='middle' style="width:100%;
    background: #8FC;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    bottom: 30px;">
  <div id='left' style="background: #FFF;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: scroll;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;">
  </div>
  <div id='right' style="background: #CF8;
    position: absolute;
    left: 25%;
    top: 0;
    width: 75%;
    height: 100%;">
    <div id='charts' style="background: #DF7;
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      top:0;
      height:60%;">
CHARTS GO HERE
    </div>
    <div id='sliders' style="background: #BF9;
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      bottom:0;
      height:40%;">
SLIDERS GO HERE
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id='footer' style="width:100%;
    background: #8CF;
    position: absolute;
    height: 30px;
    font-size: 100%;
    bottom: 0;">footer</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/n3yhqcte/ :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if it is trivial, but I surely hope, that the overflow: auto is set on the div you want to be scrolled...

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar scroll issue with the dijit.Tree. What I discovered is that the Tree inherits behavior from the ContentPane, this means that in terms of layout policy it will behave as a ContentPane. Here is the solution for my problem:

css class:

```
.TreeHeightClass {
   height: 350;
   overflow: scroll;
}
```

apply the class to your "tree":

```
domClass.add(treeControl.domNode, "TreeHeightClass");
```

Hope this solves your issues.

Regards